# NSObject call to self gives XCode error

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios6, xcode4.2, implicit-conversion, nsobject

I have a class WebServices that inherits from NSObject. I am using xcode4.2 and ARC turned on.
When I created the class, there was no other method in the NSObject lie viewDidLoad or init.

The issues is that when I try to call self.something or [self someMethod] Xcode flags my code red and complains with:

**implicit conversion of Objective-C pointer type 'Class' to C pointer type 'struct obj_class*' requires a bridge cast**

Please help. Why isn't cocoa like java where you call "this" and get the object you are in?

```
// WebService.h file
@interface WebService : NSObject

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString * myString;
+(void) setAndPrintMyString:(NSString*) someString;

@end



//WebService.m file


#import "WebService.h"
@implementation WebService

@synthesize myString=_myString;

+(void) printMyString:(NSString*) someString{
 [self setMyString:someString];      //XCode does not allow
 NSLog(@"myString is set to %@",self.myString); //XCode dose not allow
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are trying

Comment: @Paul.s I added some code from work, so I apologies if the code has typos, I didn't get to run it before posting.

Comment: The code you have posted works fine for me - either you need to post the actual code so we can see the real issue or Xcode is playing up

Comment: @Paul.s updated my code ... I had a +(void) not -(void) which I thing now makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring a method with `+` means that it is a class method. Within a class method `self` refers to the class itself, which in your case would be `[WebService class]`. If you declared and instance method (using `-`) then inside the method `self` would refer to the instance, which is what you want.

To set an instance variable - you need an instance

```
WebService *webService = [[WebService alloc] init];
webService.myString = @"some string";
```

Now to make your method work you need to declare it with a `-` instead of `+` which makes it an instance method

```
- (void)printMyString:(NSString *)someString
{
  [self setMyString:someString];
  NSLog(@"myString is set to %@",self.myString);
}
```

Now

```
[webService printMyString:@"boom"];
```

results in the instance variable `myString` being set to `boom` and the console logging out `myString is set to boom".

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` method doesn't fit with `NSObject` subclass. It's a method for `UI` which will be there in `UIViewController` subclasses.

Now, Coming to point about `self.something` OR `[self someMethod]`, That works perfectly well with `NSObject` subclasses. You need to show us the code, in which you are facing problem.

*Just for your reference (I think you should start developing for iOS after going through this):*

- [NSObject Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSObject)
- [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)